# Why is MySQL8.0 using filesort in this case?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `index_no_type` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `no` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_no_type` (`no`,`type`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

then query

1.why using filesort? why the query not just sort by the index

```
explain SELECT `no`,`type` from index_no_type WHERE `no`="1" and `type`=1 ORDER BY `no`,`type`;
```

[image]

2.the other query not using filesort?

```
explain SELECT `no`,`type` from index_no_type WHERE `no`="1" and `type`=1 ORDER BY `type`;
```

[image]

3.order by with column no,then using filesort

```
explain SELECT `no`,`type` from index_no_type WHERE `no`="1" and `type`=1 ORDER BY `no`;
```

[image]

***more info***:

find that,in version 8.0.12 is not using filesort,but 8.0.16,8.0.23 does

Comment: you are ordering by on a variable length data type, so it will use a filesort in this case, which is why it uses the exact index when you order by just the int.

Comment: no has varchar so it uses filesort to provide correct data. Try increase **sort_buffer_size** to get better performance. `In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the WHERE clause`.